# Trying to filter out values in a sequence that are not in another sequence

Tags: f#

I am trying to filter out values from a sequence, that are not in another sequence. I was pretty sure my code worked, but it is taking a long time to run on my computer and because of this I am not sure, so I am here to see what the community thinks.

Code is below:

```
let statezip =
    StateCsv.GetSample().Rows
    |> Seq.map (fun row -> row.State)
    |> Seq.distinct

type State = State of string

let unwrapstate (State s) = s
let neededstates (row:StateCsv) = Seq.contains (unwrapstate row.State) statezip
```

I am filtering by the neededstates function. Is there something wrong with the way I am doing this?

```
let datafilter =
    StateCsv1.GetSample().Rows
    |> Seq.map (fun row -> row.State,row.Income,row.Family)
    |> Seq.filter neededstates
    |> List.ofSeq
```

I believe that it should filter the sequence by the values that are true, since neededstates function is a bool. StateCsv and StateCsv1 have the same exact structure, although from different years.

Comment: Roughly how many lines are in the CSV files being processed?

Comment: tens of thousands

Comment: Tens of thousands is a good candidate for using a `Set`.  If the sequence was very small, then the cost of materializing the sequence into a set would be larger than the overhead of doing the `contains` on the sequence.  On the other hands, if the sequence was extremely large, it may not be possible to materialize the entire sequence into a set.  However, tens of thousands is in the range where materializing the sequence into set using `Set.ofSeq` will give considerable speedup.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Evaluation of `contains` on sequences and lists can be slow.  For a case where you want to check for the existence of an element in a collection, the F# `Set` type is ideal.  You can convert your sequences to sets using `Set.ofSeq`, and then run the logic over the sets instead.  The following example uses the numbers from 1 to 10000 and then uses both sequences and sets to filter the result to only the odd numbers by checking that the values are not in a collection of even numbers.

Using Sequences:

```
let numberSeq = {0..10000}
let evenNumberSeq = seq { for n in numberSeq do if (n % 2 = 0) then yield n }

#time
numberSeq |> Seq.filter (fun n -> evenNumberSeq |> Seq.contains n |> not) |> Seq.toList
#time
```

This runs in about 1.9 seconds for me.

Using sets:

```
let numberSet = numberSeq |> Set.ofSeq
let evenNumberSet = evenNumberSeq |> Set.ofSeq

#time
numberSet |> Set.filter (fun n -> evenNumberSet |> Set.contains n |> not)
#time
```

This runs in only 0.005 seconds.  Hopefully you can materialize your sequences to sets before performing your `contains` operation, thereby getting this level of speedup.

Comment: Great I appreciate the insight. Was I right in thinking that the contains function that I mentioned above does work, if I filter by it?

Comment: Yes, provided the standard equality comparison works for the objects in your sequence, the `contains` function should work.  It will just be slow for larger sequences.

Comment: Okay great. The function was running for 15 minutes, before i gave up. Which was absolutely ridiculous. I will try this.

Comment: The expensive operation is only the `contains` so it should run even faster when combining the `numberSeq` with the `evenNumberSet`, which also cunningly avoids the (unmeasured) overhead of creating `numberSet`. This way you can filter for values in very large datasets while still maintaining `O(N)` characteristics (`Set.contains` is `O(1)`).